# Sql Reporting Services Subscription Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

The Current Action cannot be completed because the user data source credentials that are required to execute this report are not stored in the report server database

Comment: Are all your parameter values set to something in the subsciption?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your datasources for your reports. There are two settings.

- User can supply them.
- Or they can be stored in DB.

They need to be stored in DB for subscriptions (at least that's how the error reads). See if you can modify your datsources.

Answer (score 1):

please ignore if you had already solved it.

This issue may also happen if default user credentials (like windows userID) do not have enough permissions to run a piece of SQL script or a SP. We can go to SQL server report configuration and select an option to ask for credentials every time you run a report.
You can provide the correct user id paswd when prompted?

Praveen